# Pressing left Option key shows the Desktop

Tags: macos

I am using my first MacBook, MacBook Air 2020 with an M1 chip.

Everything was going normal, but I realized today when I click the left <kbd>option</kbd>  key it shows the Desktop. Even when I press <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>option</kbd> or any other key with <kbd>option</kbd>, it shows the Desktop.

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please look in **System Preferences** > **Mission Control** > **Keyboard and Mouse Shortucs** > **Show Desktop**, and set it to **-** to disable it, or change the _keyboard shortcut_ to something else.  The _default_ is: **F11**

Comment: subas kandel, I assumed it was you that upvoted my comment, so I have posted it as an answer so you may mark it as the accepted answer if you so choose. Please have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)   Thanks.

Comment: It was me upvoted the comment, as being the most likely explanation.

Comment: @Tetsujin, Thanks,  I'll leave the answer for now and if it's not the cause of the issue, I'll just delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Please look in **System Preferences** > **Mission Control** > **Keyboard and Mouse Shortucs** > **Show Desktop**, and set it to **-** to disable it, or change the *keyboard shortcut* to something else.  The *default* is: **F11**

Comment: Thank you sir, But when I checked first there was the F11 key as default then I change into Left option then again changes into F11 now the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

In MacOS Ventura 13.4.1, there are two places where you need to update the settings,

**1. System Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Mission Control -> Show Desktop**

**2. System Settings -> Desktop & Dock -> shortcuts(under Mission Control section) -> Show Desktop**

One needs to configure the preferred keyboard shortcut in both places to prevent 'Left Option' key being used as a shortcut for 'Show Desktop'.